# torsocks nicotine+ gives me errors please help

Tags: apt, python, python3

I need use torsocks for nicotine+ ...when I run "torsocks nicotine"  I have this errors:

```
GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
1626685826 WARNING torsocks[29580]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 217. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:488)
1626685826 WARNING torsocks[29581]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 217. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:488)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/gtkgui/frame.py", line 2618, in do_activate
    self.ci_mode
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/gtkgui/frame.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.port
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/pynicotine.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.protothread = slskproto.SlskProtoThread(self.network_callback, self.queue, self.bindip, self.port, port_range, self.network_filter, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/slskproto.py", line 453, in __init__
    self._p.listen(1)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operación no permitida
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/gtkgui/frame.py", line 2618, in do_activate
    self.ci_mode
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/gtkgui/frame.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.port
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/pynicotine.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.protothread = slskproto.SlskProtoThread(self.network_callback, self.queue, self.bindip, self.port, port_range, self.network_filter, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pynicotine/slskproto.py", line 453, in __init__
    self._p.listen(1)
PermissionError: [Errno 1]
```

Please helpme thanks in advance